# Tensorboard not running, Tensorflow missing attribute train

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I use Visual Studio, Python 3.6(64-bit) and i have installed tensorflow (3.5, 64-bit), tensorboard (1.9.0) and tflearn (0.3.2) on Windows 10.

I have seen a lot of issues resolved on the same subject, but none have been efficient to solve mine.
I am training a neuronal network to make edge detection, which is more or less working, but I would like to monitor the training.
I make it using tflearn.

The line for the training is the following :

```
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=3, checkpoint_path='edge-classifier.tfl.ckpt',tensorboard_dir="logs",)
```

So now I should just get the 'logs' file which is in the same folder than my programm by using the command line (by the way, the file is correctly created in my folder by my programm):

```
tensorboard --logdir=training:F:\Dev\Embryo\Version2\TrainingCellsV2\TrainingCellsV2\logs
```

as I have seen it in many issues resolution on GitHub or else.

But it always get me the same answer :

[enter image description here][1]

```
File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\beholder\beholder.py", line 192, in <module>
class BeholderHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'train'
```

And in fact even if I just write the line : tensorboard
in my windows Shell (opened in administrator mode)
I always got the same mistake :

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'train'
```

But when I check with python I can clearly see that there ain't any problem with the attribute 'train' in tensorflow :

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.train
<module 'tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api.train' from     'C:\\Users\\bcerisier\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\tools\\api\\generator\\api\\train\\__init__.py'>
```

So I really don't see what to do, please help me, I can't get away with this since two days haha !

Comment: "tensorflow (3.5, 64-bit)" what do you mean by that?

Comment: It's my version of tensorflow

Comment: Latest version is 1.9

Comment: Yep you're right don't know why it is written that way on visual... Anyway i have tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0